# Office plant identification and care

Tags: identification, plant-care, office-gardening

At my work, everyone has his own plant and needs to take care of it. I was wondering if you guys could help me out taking care of my plant.

A picture of my plant can be seen below.

So, by that, I have a couple of questions:

1. What's the name of this plant?
2. What is the best way to take care of this plant?

[image: My plant]

Comment: Well it's some sort of fern, but I don't know what kind.

Comment: Possibly Polypodium formosanum, although I can't be certain. It looks a little dried out and sunburnt - most ferns prefer moist, well drained soil and filtered light,  and it could possibly use a repotting or feed.

Comment: Are there brown markings under the leaves. Possibly a greyish brown colour, they appear down the spine of the leaf, and to the touch, are somewhat noticeable?

Comment: Ia agree, it is a Polypodium.

Comment: Nice idea! I want to work in your office!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope it's still alive,

It's definitely a fern, which usually grows beneath the canopy of trees where it's usually shaded and humid. Picture a walk through a misty forest, full of moss and ferns in their home. Humidity and mild lighting are key. Keep it away from ceiling lights because they're fluorescent lights which are actually used in horticulture to cultivate seedlings and propagate cuttings. Keep it about midway from ceiling lights, away from any direct sunlight and mist it with a spray bottle two or three times a day.

Oh and this applies to all plants, **Please do not over water them, it will drown and the roots and they will die, roots require oxygen(or can live in high amounts of dissolved oxygen in the water which must be maintained at certain temperatures ), only water when the soil feels almost dry to the touch**, but if you can, one watering every 4-8 weeks, depending of type of plant, you want to thoroughly flush the root system out with mildly fertilized water using a fertilizer specified for the type of plant you're caring for, in usually half the dose specified on the package because  **with fertilizer more is BAD**.

I hope I could help. :)

Comment: It's still alive, but thanks for your answer! I didn't knew you only have to water it every 4-8 weeks :o I just gave it some every friday. Not too much because the ground was still a little bit wet/soft.

Comment: You should only flush it out with mild fertilizer every 4-8 weeks,but water as needed (when the soil is almost dry to touch) and you'll have a happy plant.

Comment: @user14828 some of the leafs are partially brown, should we remove those?