# Orange spots on Polypodium

Tags: diseases, plant-care, office-gardening

A few months ago I asked a what kind of plant my office plant is and how to take care of it. I got a [clear answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/office-plant-identification-care/25080#25080) on that recently, but I just discovered orange spots on some of the leaves (NOT ALL!).

I've made 2 photos to give you a clearer idea of what I mean.

Does someone know what those spots are (and if they are dangerous or something)? And does it need some kind of a cure?

[image: Detailed view]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't get a close enough image to examine the spots thoroughly, but because they're evenly spaced, its most likely these are sporangia, or spore cases. It's a sign of a healthy plant and the spores are produced as part of the reproductive process.

Rust infection can be a problem on these plants in some areas, but the orange spots are randomly spaced, so if the plant seems otherwise very healthy, they're spore cases.

http://beyondthehumaneye.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/polypody-fern-with-golden-sporangia.html

Comment: Yes, they are spore cases.